# Java Youtube credentials?

Tags: java, youtube-api

I'm facing a problem with youtube java credentials,normally it works well and i was able to upload to youtube, but today i' m getting this exception invalid credentials.

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("id", developer_key);

try {
    service.setUserCredentials(login, "pass);
} catch (AuthenticationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
>

 com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials 11:23:07,915 ERROR [STDERR]
 at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenF‌​actory.java:660) 11:23:07,915 ERROR [STDERR] 
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFacto‌​ry.java:560) 11:23:07,915 ERROR [STDERR] 
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthToke‌​nFactory.java:397)
```

Comment: I didn 't modify the code, i m still using the same one.                    here is the error i have  com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
11:23:07,915 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:660)
11:23:07,915 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
11:23:07,915 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)

Comment: I am getting the same problem. They must have changed something on the server. Not sure what the problem is. They may have disabled ClientLogin?

Comment: Quick update. One of my accounts(staging) has started working, but the other one still returns BadAuthentication. I think the problem is slowly resolving itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2013/04/17/google-mail-and-other-services-disrupted/?intcmp=HPBucket

Might be related. I'd say try again as it may well have been a temporary glitch.

Comment: This seems like the likely culprit. Still not working, but I bet it will be fixed in the morning

Comment: I tried again but i still have the same problem, hope it has a relation with what jwenting mentioned.

Comment: Hey kungfoo, did you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with `Youtube credentials`, but since this is java code so I am just guessing from the examples I have seen on the net..

Try

```
service.setUserCredentials(login, pass);    //remove quotes
```

instead of:

```
service.setUserCredentials(login, "pass);
```

Comment: it is not this problem, because i ve just wanted not to put my login and my pass on sof and i forgot to delete the quote

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking [ClientLogin #FAIL](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4442 for more information. Let's consolidate the discussion there.